setInterval() alternative for web for inactive windows/ tabs
The setInterval() web API does not work when the browser tab is inactive. Is there any alternative for it that can keep the timer intact even when the browser tab/ window is inactive?

apparently it "works" in Web Workers ... seen a LOT of questions like yours answered that way

You can use Web Workers to run tasks in the background without being affected by the browser’s throttling mechanisms.
